# How should we reduce the number of files generated by nuxt generate?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js, cloudflare

We generate our Jamstack site with nuxt generate and deploy to Cloudflare. [Going Full Static](https://nuxtjs.org/announcements/going-full-static/). However we have a problem with frequent failures to deploy to Cloudflare. We contacted Cloudflare and were told we had too many deploy files.

So we want to reduce the number of files generated by nuxt generate. How can we configure our settings to reduce the number of files generated? For example, is there a setting that combines some of the generated files into one?

Initially, we tried to reduce the file size and display it more quickly. However, as it is now, deployments fail and information is not updated. We are now willing to sacrifice a little file size and display speed in order to always provide the latest information.

We have not added any special settings. Part of nuxt.config.js is as follows.

```js
export default {
  target: 'static',

  build: {
    html: {
      minify: {
        collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
        decodeEntities: true,
        minifyCSS: false,
        minifyJS: false,
        processConditionalComments: true,
        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        trimCustomFragments: true,
        useShortDoctype: true,
      },
    },
  },

  generate: {
    subFolders: false,
  },
}
```

We tried the following settings to no avail.

```js
export default {
   splitChunks: {
      layouts: false,
      pages: false,
      commons: false
   }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, Cloudflare is not a hosting platform, just a middleware CDN. Where exactly do you host your Nuxt app? Also, what is the exact reason Cloudflare gave you? Because you probably cannot reduce the amount of static pages (you could have some as SPAs tho). I mean, if you want to have `/blog/123`, I'm not sure how you could get rid of it. SSG will always be having a lot of static files, that's the whole point of the thing. Also, how many pages do you have? This is not a `nuxt.config.js` issue so far, more of some other limitations + scaling challenge.

Comment: @kissu Thanks for your reply. The deploy result just shows "Failed: an internal error occurred in Cloudflare Pages" so we contacted them. Cloudflare informed us that due to the large number of files, deployments were likely to fail. We only use GitHub, Cloudflare Pages and Route 53 in this configuration. Cloudflare are aware that it is their problem and plan to try to retry if they fail to deploy. Our site map shows 3602 url's. Many files are generated in the dist folder. Combining some of these into one file would reduce the number of files. Is there such a setup?

Comment: I'm not sure how you place to have a combination of routes because it's static files (you cannot have a logic like this). You can always go SSR but this is making a lot of change just to solve one issue. I'd recommend digging the Cloudflare issue rather than making such a big shift.

Comment: @kissu Thanks for your reply again. Your answer does not seem to mesh with our question. It seems that our problem is not communicated to you correctly because of our poor English. We give up trying to get an answer to this question.